# How to show content based on object property value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page that loads the following object:

```
var fields = {"age":"on","email":"useremail@gmail.com","firstname":"John","lastname":"Smith","officialrules":"on","question":"a"};
```

The value for each property is dynamic and changes based on what the user has entered on a previous page.

The last property, **question**, can either have the value of **a** OR **b** OR **c**.

In my HTML of the page, there are three hidden divs (each containing a style of display:none).

```
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
<div id="div3"></div>
```

Using Javascript or jQuery, how can I show a specific div based on the value in the **question** property?

In other words, all the three divs are set as default to display none.

- If the **question** property contains the value **a**, I want **div1** to display as block.
- If the **question** property contains the value **b**, I want **div2** to display as block.
- If the **question** property contains the value **c**, I want **div3** to display as block.

When I play around in the console on my browser, I'm able to achieve the behavior I want when I put the following line of code:

```
if (fields.question == 'a') {document.getElementById('div1').style.display='block';}
```

But how can I make a script that will work automatically with all three scenarios? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename the divs to diva, divb, divc, etc. and do

```
var id = 'div' + fields.question;
var div = document.getElementById(id);
if( div ) div.style.display = 'block';
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GkmX2/

This is a bit more extensible since you can add additional divs without updating the code.

Comment: THIS IS AWESOME! I couldn't figure out how to solve it.... but this is what worked for me:

 <script type="text/javascript">
  $( function() {
   var id = 'div' + fields.question;
   var div = document.getElementById(id);
   if( div ) div.style.display = 'block';
  });
 </script>

Comment: I am new to Javascript – can you please explain me what's going on here that made it work? I want to understand why it worked and what I need to learn to know this.

Comment: @Ori I'll be happy to, but can you be more specific in your question? Which line(s) don't make sense? Line 1: Get the div id (diva, divb, divc). Line 2: Get the document element object. See http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementbyid.asp Line 3: Set the display to block on the div object.

Comment: @Ori Perhaps what you are looking for is understanding the DOM (Document Object Model). See http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_document.asp for an introduction.

Answer (score 2):

in jQuery this is simple:

```
$( function() {
    if (fields.question == 'a') $( '#div1' ).show();
    if (fields.question == 'b') $( '#div2' ).show();
    if (fields.question == 'c') $( '#div3' ).show();
});
```

You can put this after `var fields` statement.

Note that `$( function() {` means that code will be executed after DOM is ready

Answer (score 0):

I would rename the dives `diva` `divb` and `divc`, then try this:

```
document.getElementById('div'+fields.question).style.display='block';
```

Answer (score 0):

If there are three fixed values you could set the id of the div the same value for the question they represent and use jquery to show the div. Like:
$("div#div"+fields.question).show();

Answer (score 0):

I think the way that I would do it would be to tie the divs to the possible values.  You could do this either with the `id` or a `class` value.  Using a `class` value would allow you to, potentially, display multiple elements, based on the `question` value (if that is needed), so I'd personally go that route, to allow for flexibility.

Something like this would do what you needed:

**HTML**

```
<div id="div1" class="a"></div>
<div id="div2" class="b"></div>
<div id="div3" class="c"></div>
```

**JS**

```
document.getElementsByClassName(fields.question).style.display='block';
```

Answer (score 0):

How about do this..

```
var showDiv = function (hideID, showID) {
   $("#" + hideID).hide();
   $("#" + showID).show();
}
```

Call the function when you want to change the Div.